# How to read what a switch does in a motherboard block diagram

Tags: motherboard, switch, diagrams

I have the basic understanding that a switch in a motherboard block diagram is suppose to show which ports/connections are usable at one time, but I'm having trouble understanding the possible combinations that you're allowed to use from the diagram.

[image: MSI Z170A Gaming M5 ATX LGA1151 Z170]

From the above diagram could you explain how the switch components works and how I can figure out the possible combinations that I would be allowed to use with this motherboard.

Comment: "Many circuits have a switch so that they can be turned on and off. When the switch is off, it makes a gap in the circuit and the electrons are not able to flow around. When the switch is turned on, it closes the gap and the electricity is able to move and make the device work."

Answer (score 0):

No, that diagram is just a generalized diagram of how your motherboard is splitting things out; there's no real information on how or what could be physically connected to where on the motherboard.  You'd also need to let us know what you're attempting to do as right now there's not enough information to guess even that.  If you're trying to install a graphics card or two, you'll want to put them in the PCIe slots that have the highest "x" number.  If it has x16 slots, you'll want them in those, or if it only has x8s, use them instead.